# c# merging word's table colum's cells

Tags: c#, ms-word, word-table

I would like to merge cells from startRowIndex until startRowIndex+length.
I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.
For example:

| Column 0 | Column 1 |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell x |
| Cell 2 | Cell x |
| Cell 3 | Cell x |
| Cell 4 | Cell x |
| Cell 5 | Cell x |
| Cell 6 | Cell x |

My goal:

| Column 0 | Column 1 |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell x |
| Cell 1 | Cell x |
| Cell 1 | Cell x |
| Cell 2 | Cell x |
| Cell 2 | Cell x |
| Cell 2 | Cell x |

(as you can see i would like to skip the header row)

Here is my function i would like to use:

```
public void MergeUp(int firstCell = 1, int length = 2, int targetColumn = 0)
```

For this reason I would like to call this twice.

I tried many times, but I got exceptions like the cell is deleted, cannot merge multiple cells.

```
public void MergeUp(int firstCell = 1, int length = 2, int targetColumn = 0)
{
    if (firstCell < 1 || length < 2)
    {
        return;
    }
    if(Table.Rows.Count <3)
    {
        return;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < length-1; i++)
    {
        var target = Table.Cell(firstCell, targetColumn);
        var current = Table.Cell(firstCell+1, targetColumn);
        target.Merge(current);
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to merge each cell into the first merged target, you can't merge sequentially. In other words: 2 and 3 into 1. Not 2 into 1 and 3 into 2.